# Передача параметра функции вида (Params: Int*) в другую функцию

Tags: scala

Есть такой код:

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println(test1(1, 5, 8))
  }
  def test1(params: Int*): Int = {
    if (params.length > 1) test2(params) // -- ERROR
    else params(0)
  }
  def test2(params: Int*): Int = {
    params.sum
  }
}
```

Возникает ошибка ERROR:

> Error:(9, 34) type mismatch;  found   : Seq[Int]  required: Int
> if (params.length > 1) test2(params)

А как можно передать params в функцию test2 для дальнейшей обработки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```scala
if (params.length > 1) test2(params: _*)
```

таким же образом можно передавать и другие последовательности

```scala
test2(List(1,2,3): _*)
```